# inspect array in controller rails and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to inspect my array with all relation (belognTo and hasMany) in ruby and rail  without loop in controller file. is there any way such like a php? I have try this

```
abort(@microposts.inspect)
```

but error is coming. Who can do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by inspect? Do you want to print it in logs?

Comment: yes I want to print it

Comment: You can try with `raise @microposts.inspect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
logger.debug "microposts---------->#{@microposts.inspect}"
```

The above line will print the micropost object in your console log

I suggest that you check [Ruby on Rails Debugging Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html).

Comment: I want to print in controller and this is not working

Comment: where i can write down this and how ?

Comment: undefined method `debig' for #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0xbf5c7f0> this is my code "def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
 logger.debig "microposts---------->#{@microposts.inspect}"
  end"

Comment: oh sorry my bad ... It's `debug` thanx khaled